# Media item upload request

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library

Is there a way to check if the request is coming from `Browse for media files`

[image: Browse for media files]

Or is it coming `upload file` or `upload files`

[image: Upload file or files]

I have code to check upload image size

```
public class ImageSizeCheck : UploadProcessor
    {
        public List<string> RestrictedExtensions { get; set; }

        public ImageSizeCheck()
        {
            RestrictedExtensions = new List<string>();
        }

        public void Process(UploadArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
            if (args.Destination == UploadDestination.File)
                return;

            foreach (string index in args.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = args.Files[index];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName) && IsRestrictedExtension(file.FileName))
                {
                    if ((long)file.ContentLength > MaxImageSizeInDatabase)
                    {
                        String message = string.Format("The image {0} can not be uploaded. The maximum size should be {1}.", file.FileName, MainUtil.FormatSize(MaxImageSizeInDatabase));
                        args.ErrorText = message;
                        Log.Warn(args.ErrorText, this);
                        message = "\"" + message + "\"";
                        string str = "<script>alert(" + message + ")</script>";
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(str);
                        args.AbortPipeline();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsRestrictedExtension(string filename)
        {
            return RestrictedExtensions.Exists(restrictedExtension => string.Equals(restrictedExtension, Path.GetExtension(filename), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        }

        public static long MaxImageSizeInDatabase
        {
            get
            {
                return Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetLongSetting("Media.MaxImageSizeInDatabase", 524288000L);
            }
        }
    }
```

The alert is working for `UploadFile` or `UploadFiles` but it is giving error for `Browse for media files`.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

[image: error]

If I find that if the request is coming from `Browse for media files` then I can skip **HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(str);**

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the message should display meaningful message rather than unexpected json token message.

Could you please perform the following steps to make it display the meaningful message:

Open the `Uploader.js` via `<sitecore_instance>\sitecore\shell\client\Business Component Library\Layouts\Renderings\Forms\Uploader`
Find the following upload method:

```
upload: function ()
```

**Replace the above upload method code with the following:**

`upload: function () { var that = this;       this.startUploadTimer(this.datas);       this.updateUploadInfo(true, true);`

```
  //for each files - do the upload
  _.each(this.datas, function (data) {
    data.submit().error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
        _sc.Helpers.session.unauthorized();
        return;
      }
      // Triggers error on each model that had an abort
      if (jqXHR.responseText.indexOf('errorItems') != -1) {
        var errordata = jqXHR.responseText.split('</html>');
        var parsedJson = JSON.parse(errordata[1]);
        _.each(parsedJson.errorItems[1].Message, function (error) {
          error.id = data.__id;
        });
        var errors = [{ Message: parsedJson.errorItems[1].Message }];
        that.app.trigger("sc-error", errors);
        that.app.trigger("upload-error", { id: data.__id, errors: parsedJson.errorItems[1].Message });

        return undefined;
      }
      else{
        if (errorThrown === "abort") {
          that.app.trigger("upload-error", { id: data.__id });
        } else {
          var errors = [{ Message: errorThrown }];
          that.app.trigger("sc-error", errors);
          that.app.trigger("upload-error", { id: data.__id, errors: errors });
        }
      } 
    });
  });
},
```

After you perform the above steps, you should be able to see the meaningful message display on the upload media about why the media item is not uploaded successfully.